# Can I lace a XTR rear hub with thirty two spokes from a Valiant asymmetrical rim to a thirty two hole Magic regular rim?

Tags: mountain-bike, compatibility

Can I lace a XTR rear hub with thirty two spokes from a Valiant asymmetrical rim to a thirty two hole Magic regular rim?

Comment: What are these "valiant asymmetrical" and "standard magic"? Pictures or links would help.

Comment: I'd guess an asymmetrical rim has that subtly different nipple hole pattern so the NDS spokes are at a steeper angle than the DS spokes.   Please confirm.  Valiant is a brand name?   Standard Magic means nothing to me - perhaps write your native language into Google Translate at https://translate.google.com/ and post the english version in here.

Comment: First off, check if the hub flanges have been worn by the spokes. This somewhat limits the lacing pattern possibility to what was there before. But if both rims are 32 holes, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Does magic possibly mean MAVIC, the rim maker?

Comment: @Criggie : asymmetric rims may have either an asymmetric profile or nipple holes alternatively left and right or even both features like those Campy G3 pattern wheels.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. The hub doesn't really care whether its spokes are laced to an asymmetric rim or not.

However, you may not be able to reuse the spokes--regardless of whether you're switching between an asymmetric rim and a "straight" rim, the spoke lengths may well not be close enough because of different rim depths. You'll need to check a spoke-length calculator.